# VHDL counter simulated using a test bench giving 'Uninitialized' for the output, how is this resolved?

Tags: vhdl, counter, simulation, vivado, test-bench

Below is a counter that is designed to represent an 8 bit binary number with 8 LEDs, it is being simulated using a test bench, however when running the simulation the output simply shows UU for the led.

Here is the main entity that I wish to test:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.all;

entity Lab_3_Source_File is
 generic(N_BITS : integer := 8);
 port(
 btnd : in STD_LOGIC ;
 clk : in STD_LOGIC;
 led : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
 );
end Lab_3_Source_File;

architecture counter of Lab_3_Source_File is
signal count: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

begin

process(clk, btnd)
begin
 if btnd = '1' then
 count <= (others => '0');
 elsif rising_edge(clk) then
 count <= count + 1;
 end if;
end process;

 led <= count;
end counter;
```

Here is the test bench that I have tried to map to the main entity:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity Count_TestBench is

end Count_TestBench;

architecture Behavioral of Count_TestBench is                               
                   
    signal btnd, clk : STD_LOGIC;
    signal led : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
begin


   UUT : entity work.Lab_3_Source_File port map (btnd => btnd,clk => clk,led => led);
 
    process
    begin
        btnd<='1';
        wait for 1 ns;
        btnd<='0';    
        led<= (others => '0');           
        for i in 1 to 100 loop
            clk<='1';
            wait for 10 ns;
            clk<='0';
            wait for 10 ns;
            led<=led;
        end loop;          
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Please could somebody help me understand how to enable the simulation to display the led output incrementing?

EDIT:

Set btnd to 1 with a 1ns wait in the test bench to initialise the led, following the answer from mkrieger1, the led output is still at U following this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is not initialized inside `Lab_3_Source_File` until `btnd` is set to `'1'`, which it isn't in the testbench.

Since the `led` output is driven by `count`, it is also uninitialized. The uninitialized value of the `led` output of `Lab_3_Source_File` is then assigned to the `led` signal in the testbench.

So, to fix this, you need to set `btnd` to `'1'` once for a non-zero duration in the testbench, before setting it to `'0'` again (otherwise `led` is held at `"00000000"` constantly).

Comment: Appreciate your help, and I have made this change (see the edit) however the output for the led is still uninitialized in the simulation

Comment: @DataKing There's something special you're doing when the `clk` signal gets toggled, which is missing for `btnd`…

Comment: When you write `btnd <= '1'; btnd <= '0'`, the signal is *not* actually set to `'1'` because the second assignment overwrites the first one immediately. You need to let some amount of time pass between those assignments (by using `wait`).

Comment: Directly below ````btnd<='1'; ```` (see edit) I have tried adding ````wait;```` and ````wait for 1 ns;```` oddly, the output for the led was UU and XX respectively!

Comment: What if you remove both `led<= (others => '0');` and `led<=led;` in the testbench? They don't seem to make any sense to me, since the `led` signal in the testbench is already driven by the `led` output of `Lab_3_Source_File`.

Comment: Yes! This worked! They were artefacts from previous attempts to resolve this issue. Thank you so much for your help with this.